# Play with matchsticks

Tags: lateral-thinking, matches

By moving only **1** matchstick make the equation correct (not equal and > and < are not allowed).
[image: 119=9]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe we can simply...

> multiply?
>  [image: 119 equals 9 in matchsticks, with the top matchstick of the second one moved down and rotated slightly to make the equation 1 times 9 equals 9]

Edit:
We can also...

> Move the highlighted match and flip our perspective by 180 degrees to get 6 = SIX
>  [image: 119 equals 9 in matchsticks, with the top right matchstick of the first 9 moved to intersect with the first 1 at an angle. Flipping the perspective around by 180 degrees, this results in the equation 6 = the letters S, I, and X]

Comment: finally. both are correct but 6=six is what i expected.

Answer (score 8):

> Take the upper right matchstick from the 9 to turn it into a 5.
>  Place it across the middle of the second 1 to turn it into +.
>  You now have 1 + 5 = 9. Look at it upside down and it's 6 = 5 + 1

Comment: A lopsided operation symbol for sure, but it seems valid to me. Nice job!

Comment: hmm, it's close to intended answer.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by others, with little lateral thinking if any.

> [image]
>
>  i.e. $1^1 9 = 9$

Comment: Very nice idea!

Answer (score 3):

Not proud of my solution.

> Take a match from a "1", light it, burn the 3 others to get 9=9.

Comment: It was an interesting solution ;D

Answer (score 2):

May be a long shot

> Move one of the matchstick from the second I and join it to its bottom matchstick to create v. Then rotate the image to get

> 6 = 6 ^ 1

Answer (score 0):

Shortening [DrD](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34419/drd) shot:

> Move second "1" down, just placing the top stick below the one below, so rotating 180 degrees you see: 6^1*1=6 . Without the operators ofc :)